# Why can I read data from postgres in docker container with sqlalchemy, but can't write data to postgres with sqlalchemy?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am experiencing really weird behavior when trying to work with data in a dockerized postgres container. I have set up a docker-compose file, to have two containers, one with a postgres db, and another python container running a jupyter notebook. I know that my connection is correct because I am able to query data from the database (I initialize the database with a sql file, that is a dump from a database on my local machine). I am able to query, but I am unable to write to the db. Not sure what is going on or why. I don't get an error when trying to write to the db, it returns what I expect with the number of rows added to the db. Has anyone experienced this before?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, URL, inspect

CONFIG = dotenv_values('.env')
if not CONFIG:
    CONFIG = os.environ

    
url_object = URL.create(
        drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
        username=CONFIG['POSTGRES_USER'],
        password=CONFIG['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        host=CONFIG['POSTGRES_HOST'],
        database=CONFIG['POSTGRES_DB'],
    )

engine = create_engine(url_object)

query = text("""select * from tbl1;""")

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=query, con=engine.connect())

df.head(n=1)
```

This returns the first row of the table as expected. Then when I inspect the tables in the database, it shows all the tables I am adding in the initializing sql script, as expected

```
insp = inspect(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

Returns:

```
['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']
```

When I try and write data to the database, it doesn't throw an error but the table doesn't get added.

```
test_tbl = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 3]})

test_tbl.to_sql(name="test_tbl", con=engine.connect(), if_exists='replace')
```

Returns:

```
2
```

When I check to see if the new table was added, it shows the same tables from the initialization script

```
insp = inspect(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

Returns:

```
['tbl1', 'tbl2', 'tbl3']
```

Then when I try and query from the new table, it throws an error: "ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "test_tbl" does not exist"

```
pd.read_sql_query(sql=text("select * from test_tbl;"), con=engine.connect())
```

Here is my docker-compose file for context:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jupyter_notebook:
    image: "jupyter/minimal-notebook"
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME:-jupyter_notebook}
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}:/home/jovyan/work
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - adu_network
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
      - "POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}"
      - "POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}"
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    expose:
      - "5433"
    networks:
      - adu_network
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./adu_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  
networks:
  adu_network: null
```

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you using?  It looks like you never commit your change, and sqlalchemy doesn't do it for you either.

Comment: @jjanes I am on SQLAlchemy 2.02. I have used this method of writing to postgres before with pandas, didn't see anything in the documentation about it not working anymore. I am also just generally very confused because the output of .to_sql is the expected number of rows written.

Comment: For more context, I just verified that I can add tables to the database (and persist them) by opening a shell in the container and using psql. Thus, the issue is definitely on the python/sqlalchemy/pandas side. Not sure why I can read the queries but can't write.